# Distance of boxes in baposter?

Tags: boxes, posters, baposter

I am making a poster using `baposter`. I couldn't figure out how to reduce the vertical distance of the boxes (and maybe allow them to have some vertical overlap). Any advice?

A sample code:

```
\documentclass[landscape,paperwidth=22in,paperheight=28in, fontscale=.5]{baposter}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\graphicspath{{images/}}
\renewcommand\refname{}

\newcommand{\RotUP}[1]{\begin{sideways}#1\end{sideways}}

 \setlength{\columnsep}{5pt}
 \setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}

\newcommand{\compresslist}{%
 \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
 \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
 \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}{
 grid=false,
 colspacing=0.5em,
 headerColorOne=cyan!20!white!90!black,
 borderColor=cyan!30!white!90!black,
 textborder=faded,
 headerborder=open,
 headershape=roundedright,
 headershade=plain,
 background=none,
 bgColorOne=cyan!10!white,
 boxheaderheight=.5cm,
 headerheight=0.1\textheight}    
{Header}{}{}

\headerbox{\large Contribution:}{name=contribution,column=0,row=0,span=2}{
First box}

\headerbox{\large Introduction}{name=theory,column=0,row=0,span=2, below=contribution}{
Second box}



\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a small, complete code example? (Just so that everyone who would like to look at this doesn't have to make up their own.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT.
\setlength{\columnsep}{5pt} determines the horizontal distance of columns in the poster (therefore, the horizontal distance of boxes as well). I have no idea how the code for vertical distance of boxes should look like. By boxes I mean page 2 of http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/baposter/baposter_guide.pdf

Comment: OK, but that was not what I asked for. I asked for example code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. Just make the simplest poster possible with two boxes, and add that code to your question.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.
Sorry. Code dded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row placement is defined by the `row=` key. `row` takes a real number corresponding to the proportion of the `\textheight` (here your paper height minus the margins minus the poster header).

So `row=0.1` places the box at a distance 0.1\textheight from the top of the poster area. If you use the relative placement keys like `below=` or `align=`, this will override the `row=` definition

In essence, you can place a box anywhere in the column, including overlapping another box (see the example where Box 4 overlaps Box3).

I added the `headerfont` key to the MWE. It isn't necessary to use formatting macros in the `headerbox` to set their format. It can be done globally, as indicated.

This is the result:

[image]

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[landscape,paperwidth=22in,paperheight=28in, fontscale=.5]{baposter}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\graphicspath{{images/}}
\renewcommand\refname{}

\newcommand{\RotUP}[1]{\begin{sideways}#1\end{sideways}}

 \setlength{\columnsep}{5pt}
 \setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}

\newcommand{\compresslist}{%
 \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
 \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
 \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}{
 grid=false,
 colspacing=0.5em,
 headerColorOne=cyan!20!white!90!black,
 borderColor=cyan!30!white!90!black,
 textborder=faded,
 headerborder=open,
 headershape=roundedright,
 headershade=plain,
 background=none,
 bgColorOne=cyan!10!white,
 boxheaderheight=.5cm,
 headerfont=\bfseries\large,  <-- % Set headerbox format
 headerheight=0.1\textheight}    
{Header}{}{}

\headerbox{Box1:}{name=box1,column=0,row=0,span=2}
{First box}

\headerbox{Box2:}{name=box2,column=0,row=0.05,span=2}
{Second box}

\headerbox{Box3:}{name=box3,column=0,row=0.10,span=2}
{Third box}

\headerbox{Box4:}{name=box4,column=0,row=0.12,span=2}
{Fourth box}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```